# Updating table with jQuery, but browser not refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I've got a node.js and sockets app that I'm using to build a SPA. A user fills out a form to create a new lobby. When they submit it, a socket event it sent to the server, the server adds the lobby, then the server emits an event to everyone with the updated list of lobbies. When this occurs, my client side JS receives the lobby list and updates a table. While viewing the browser console, this seems to work fine. I see that the the lobby info is logged in my update_lobbies function. I see that it loops through the lobbies, and I even see the html update with the new information. However, the browser doesn't seem to update the view. If I refresh the page, which requests the same lobby information, the page will update. Also, at that point, after the refresh, future lobby updates will be visually updated for that user.

```
socket.on('lobby list', function(data){
    if(data.lobbies.length > 0){
        update_lobbies(data.lobbies);
    }
}
```

Which then calls update_lobbies():

```
const update_lobbies = (lobbies) => {
        var lobbies_table = document.getElementById('lobbies_table');
        lobbies_table.innerHTML = "";

        console.dir(lobbies);

        $("#lobbies_table").append("<tr>" + 
        "<th>" + "Name" + "</th>" +
        "<th>" + "Participants" + "</th>" +
        "<th>" + "Current State " + "</th>" +
        "<th>" + "Actions" + "</th>" +
        "</tr>");

        for (var i = 0; i < lobbies.length; i++){

            console.log("looping");

            $("#lobbies_table").append("<tr>" + 
            "<td>" + lobbies[i].name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + lobbies[i].participants.length + "/" + lobbies[i].capacity + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + lobbies[i].state + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + "<button id=\"join_lobby\" value=\"" + lobbies[i].name + "\">Join</button>" + " | " + "<button id=\"spectate_lobby\" value=\"" + lobbies[i].name + "\">Spectate</button>" + "</td>" +
            "</tr>");

        }
}
```

One thing that may be related is that I have a `e.preventDefault();` in the form to prevent the page from reloading when I submit the form. Removing this obviously 'fixes' the problem because I'm doing a reload, but I don't want to have to reload the page to get the browser to update the view. I'm not exactly storing state information yet, so reloading isn't yet an option anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was making a stupid mistake. If the page loaded and there were no lobbies, I was hiding the table. I was just forgetting to show it when lobbies were added.